# What's the easiest way to extract 8 bits from a hexadecimal?

Tags: bit-manipulation

If I wanted to extract 8 bits from a hexadecimal number and store it somewhere else, what's the most cleanest way to do this? I don't think I properly understand bit shifting. For example, 
I know that to extract a the single nth bit, it would simply be ( hex >> n ) & 1, and of course I could do this 8 times and connect them to together, but I guessing there's a much easier solution than that?

Edit: The hexadecimal is 4 bytes, and I need to be able to extract anyone of these 4 bytes.

Comment: did you want (hex >> n) & ff ?

Comment: Wait. Would that give me 8 bits back (because ff is 8 bits)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to extract 8 bits from an integer?

That's just `(number >> n) & 0xFF to get the n to n+15th bit`

If you have a hexadecimal *string*, it's a bit trickier.